# Docker - My Container can't catch my variables

Tags: docker, variables

I'm dockerizing a little script I made, it worked fine but I did something wrong and now, I can't send any env_var.
Even a simple "echo $VAR" doesn't work

[image: Result here]

Here is my docker-compose. (I added random strings for variables)

(EDITED)

```
version: '3'
services:
 bot:
  build:
   context: .
   args:
    - CLIENT_ID=9c3e
    - LOGIN=Cibre
    - PASSWORD=sie172h971342e41
    - USER_ID=3240
    - TOKEN_BOT=1120Y62B-YjoX_4LMCG7foK8
```

Now I have this error :
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgGsk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are only available at runtime, not buildtime

If you need those variables to build the container, then you want `args`

```
services:
  bot:
    build:
      context: .
      args: 
        - CLIENT_ID=9c36e
        ...
```

however, you really should not echo passwords and tokens as plaintext

Also, you cannot use `image` and `build` in Docker Compose at the same time

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the docker-compose. Now I have the error

 "[Warning] One or more build-args [CLIENT_ID LOGIN PASSWORD USER_ID TOKEN_BOT] were not consumed"

I'm editing the post to show the new docker-compose

Comment: Well, did you edit the Dockerfile to use ARG instead of ENV?